# PHPExcel missing text boxes

Tags: php, phpexcel

I need to open a existing xlsx file, that contains text boxes (those created with the predefined option like circles, squares, etc), and I need to write just behind this objects (they are transparent).

The code bellow does everything fine, except that downloads the new file without the boxes.

```
if(file_exists("app/file.xlsx")){

        $objTpl = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("app/file.xlsx");
        $objTpl->setActiveSheetIndex(1);

        $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'x');
        $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A2', 'y');
        $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A3', 'z');

        $filename = 'new_file.xlsx';
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objTpl, 'Excel2007');
        ob_end_clean();
        $ret = $objWriter->save('php://output');

        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Then you'll need to write some code for the PHPExcel Excel2007 Reader to parse and interpret them, for core PHPExcel object to maintain them, and for the PHPExcel Excel2007 Writer to write them; because they're not supported by the library

Comment: Really? Well.. lets try another strategy then. Thank you!

Comment: Really! You might look at COM (requires Windows server with MS Excel installed) or PUNO (requires server with Open/LibreOffice installed) or libXl

Answer (score 0):

you can probably do this via the COM dotnet php module

simply open the xlsx file:

```
$excel = new COM("Excel.Application") or die ("Could not initialise Object.");
            $excel->Visible       = 1;
            $excel->DisplayAlerts = 0;
            $Workbook = $excel->Workbooks->Open($file) or die("ERROR: Unable to open " . $file . "!\r\n");
            $Worksheet = $Workbook->ActiveSheet;
```

and from here on out alter your file and then use the saveas function. its all +- well documented in the developers doc from microsoft:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff198122.aspx